# Доступ к дереву iOS

Tags: ios, macos

Есть ли способ получить доступ к жесткому диску *iPhone*, работающему под управлением *iOS*, как `root` из дерева, аналогично тому, как я могу получить доступ к жесткому диску *MacBook*, работающему под управлением *macOS*?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы совершите Jailbreak и получите доступ к shell-оболочке, выполняющейся на iOS-устройстве, вы действительно получите доступ к файловой системе.

Другого способа, кроме как через Jailbreak, получить прямой доступ к диску нет – установленные программы исполняются в ограниченных контейнерах, а запустить сторонние программы не позволяют механизмы защиты самой ОС.

Никакой утилиты для низкоуровневой связи с ОС без Jailbreak наподобие Android Debug Bridge для iOS тоже не существует.

Comment: Как насчет удаленного доступа через мой Mac? Кто-то сделал это со мной, поэтому я знаю, что это возможно без джейлбрейка.

Comment: Если бы это было возможно, то и джейлбрейк бы был не нужен – рут-права есть, оболчка есть – ставим любое ПО и вперёд. Так что лучше спросите у этого кого-то, скорее всего, вы его не так поняли.

Comment: Да. Моя главная задача - найти, как это сделать с моего mac.